# Pass a string with different punctuation symbols as argv from command line

Tags: python, bash

I want to pass a string like
`"('a','a');('a','!a');('a', '!d');('b', '!e');('c','a')"`
from the command line. But i recieve an error:
`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token  '(\'`

Is there a way, how i can avoid this without adding terminal symbols?(maybe specifieng a flag)

Also, putting `\` befor brackets didn't help - which characters should i prefix with '\' in the string with no spaces?

Comment: My questing has a very general title. That makes it easier to find it, opposite to other questions

Comment: Your problem seems to be with the exclamation point, which is used for bash history searching. The question I linked to has a title specific to that.

Comment: @Barmar No, my problem was not with the exclamation point

Comment: What was the problem? None of the other punctuation characters you show have any special meaning inside double quotes.

Comment: The error message you show doesn't make any sense. It has a backslash, but there's no backslash in your string. Can you edit the question and show the actual command you were trying to enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash won't interpret strings inside single quotes so if you could switch:

```
"('a','a');('a','!a');"
```

for

```
'("a","a");("a","!a");'
```

the later with double quotes inside single quotes will work and you don't have to look at nasty escapes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), but it looks like hell:

```
$ echo "('a','a');('a','!a');('a', '!d');('b', '!e');('c','a')"
bash: !a': event not found

$ echo $'(\'a\',\'a\');(\'a\',\'!a\');(\'a\', \'!d\');(\'b\', \'!e\');(\'c\',\'a\')'
('a','a');('a','!a');('a', '!d');('b', '!e');('c','a')
```